# Mechanics of Closing a Question

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, question-closure

I'm curious how (not why) [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/204805/whats-a-word-that-means-intentionally-gullible) was closed. I see it is closed as a duplicate by one person, FumbleFingers.

I'm only familiar with closes being done by voting to close (with a required vote of up to 5, I think). When that happens, the statement about the close lists those who voted to have it closed.

In this case there is no list of voters; there is only one member named. I checked the list of moderators, and I *don't* see FumbleFinger listed among the moderators. So I'm ruling out that it was closed by a moderator.

Am I understanding this right? That one person, who is not a moderator, can close a question?

How exactly does that work (even if I got some of my facts wrong)?

Comment: Thanks. And as for the close vote on this question, I think it would be more helpful to retitle the referenced question to something that would be more meaningful in search. As it stands, the cybernetic process for matching related questions apparently doesn't have the superpowers necessary to make the connection. But, now that I understand the human process, I'm not convinced it's much better with respect to the question I referred to. (Don't get me wrong. It amazes me most of the time, but not all the time.)

Comment: Changing the title of the other one to open up with something like "How am I able to close questions alone", with or without retaining the superpowers reference, could probably work.

Comment: @GraceNote  Yes, the title should be changed, it's catchy and tongue in cheek but it doesn't help a new user understand what the subject is.

Comment: @GraceNote I've amended the title ["A single vote closes a question! Have I suddenly been granted 'superpowers'?"] and added [badges] and [vote-to-close] tags which may also help future searchers.